# Ruby on Rails Routing Similar Pages but different controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm manually writing on my routes file to redirect a 'post' request to a different action

Is there anyway to group them into 1-2 lines?

For example on my routes file, I have the following code

```
post "/users/new" => "users#create"
post "/users/edit/:id" => "users#update"

post "/user_data/new" => "user_data#create"
post "/user_data/edit/:id" => "user_data#update"

post "/status/new" => "status#create"
post "/status/edit/:id" => "status#update"
```

These are just a few and I have more than 10 controllers that uses these lines to redirect the 'new' post request to the 'create' action and the 'edit' post request to the 'update' action.

I keep repeating the same line and is there a way to create a line such like the default:

> `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :via => [:get, :post]`

something like:

```
match post :controller/new => ":controller#create"
match post :controller/edit/:id=> ":controller#update"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer on the docs:

The code I used is:

```
  match ':controller(/new)' => '(:controller)#create', via: [:post]
  match ':controller(/edit(/:id))' => '(:controller)#update', via: [:post]
```

In case somebody needs a sample.